# Button automatically clicked

Tags: react-native

I have a simple app with a Welcome class that redirects to Select class.
Select class has 2 buttons.

My problem is that when I redirect to Select class, button are automatically clicked and I have the Alert triggered without clicking.

Do you know how to prevent it ?

````
//Select.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image,ImageBackground, Linking, TouchableOpacity, Alert, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation"

export default class Select extends React.Component {

  displayMessage1(){
    Alert.alert("hello1")
  }

  displayMessage2(){
    Alert.alert("hello2")
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
          <ImageBackground
              source={require("./images/im1.jpg")}
              style={styles.imageBackground}>

                <View style ={{flex:0.3}}></View>

                <View style ={{flex:1}}>
                    <Text style ={styles.text}> myText</Text>
                </View>

                <Button
                  onPress={this.displayMessage1()}
                  title="go message 1"
                  color="#00aaf0"
                />

                <View style ={{flex:0.3}}></View>

                <Button
                  onPress={this.displayMessage2()}
                  title="go message 2"
                  color="#00aaf0"
                />

                <View style ={{flex:1}}></View>

          </ImageBackground>
        </View>
    )
  }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing displayMessage1 message on the onClick method of your button.

You should do something like, so when the event is fired, the method binded to your class will be called.

```
<Button
    onPress={this.displayMessage1.bind(this)}
    title="go message 1"
    color="#00aaf0"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button
  onPress={this.displayMessage1()} // <-- here
  title="go message 1"
  color="#00aaf0"
/>
```

That's be cause instead of passing a reference to the the `onPress` prop you are actually execution the method, so on every render that method if being called.